# Import postgresql database with Latin encoding

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, encoding, utf-8

I'm going to upgrade from postgresql 9 to postgresql 11, the encoding used is Latin.
I've exported the database using this command `pg_dumpall | gzip > /tmp/db.sql.gz`
I extracted the exported database

```
SET default_transaction_read_only = off;

SET client_encoding = 'LATIN1';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;

CREATE DATABASE db WITH TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = postgres;
```

Then I impoted the database using this command

```
psql -d postgres -f ./db.sql
```

The database is imported but when I run `l+`, I've noticed that the encoding `UTF8` is used on all databases.

Why the encoding is changed from Latin to UTF8 ? and How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you created the database with that encoding. Since your `CREATE DATABASE` statement does not explicitly specify the encoding, you will get a database with the standard encoding of the cluster, which obviously was created with `UTF8` encoding (you probably did not specify that explicitly, so `initdb` took it from your environment).

To get a `LATIN1` database, you would have to

```
/* you should also specify the correct LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE */
CREATE DATABASE db WITH ENCODING LATIN1 TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = postgres;
```

But UTF-8 actually much better; leave it like that. The database encoding should *always* be `UTF8`.  The reason for that is that you can store any character in a `UTF8` database.  Even if your current application only uses `LATIN1`, are you sure what uses the database may have 10 years from now?